# how do i create a custom navigation bar in xamarin forms for Android

Tags: xamarin.forms

how do i create a custom navigation bar [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4aob.png) in xamarin forms for Android?

I have tried using CustomNavigationRenderer and have got a reference to SupportActionBar(it is not null in the activity, nor the NavigationRenderer), But when i try to apply any changes to the actionbar, it doesn't do anything. I am using FormsAppCompatActivity.

Comment: Override Toolbar.axml with desired layout

Answer (score 0):

try below to customise the navigation bar on Android

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CustomeNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace Trainer.Droid.AndroidControls
{
public class CustomeNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
{
protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>
(Resource.Id.toolbar);
for (var i = 0; i < toolbar.ChildCount; i++)
{
var imageButton = toolbar.GetChildAt(i) as ImageButton;

        var drawerArrow = imageButton?.Drawable as DrawerArrowDrawable;
        if (drawerArrow == null)
            continue;

        imageButton.SetImageDrawable(Forms.Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.menu_icon));
    }
}
}
}
```

where "menu_icon" is any icon or image of your choice

& Set the Tile by this

```
Title = "Search Test";
```

and on the left of your toolbar like this

```
ToolbarItem new_tb = new ToolbarItem
        {
            Icon = "cart.png",

            Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary,
            Command = new Command(() => root())
        };

        ToolbarItems.Add(new_tb);
```